# Handle token change when app is in backgroud or killed

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-push-notification

I am using [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) in  my App for push notifications. It is working fine except if I get new token when app is for longer period in background or killed.
How to get new token in that case? If user start app it will read and save new token.

Answer (score 0):

When new token generated while app in background.
Save that token in local.variable and when your app restart then check new token is available or not if yes than update token on server and make new token variable empty in local storage. So that when next time token changes it will save and same process is running

Comment: Can I handle it somehow in background? Save token and send it to server?

Comment: Yes. Save in local storage. And check when you launch app again.

Comment: onRegister will bi invokend even when app is in background? I don't need to add listener?